# How to model this expression?

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

Suppose $0\le x \le 1$ is a decision variable and $\gamma(x)$ is defined as follows:
$$
\gamma(x)= \begin{cases}
\theta & x>0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
where $0\le \theta\le 1$.

In my model, I have both $\gamma(x)$ and $x \gamma(x)$ and I want to convert them to linear programs. I used the following constraints:
\begin{align}
\Gamma&\ge \theta x - (1- y )
\\
\Gamma&\le y
\\
\gamma&=\theta y
\\
y &\ge x
\end{align}

Here, the problem is that $x$ can take value 0 and then, $\gamma = \theta$ at the same time. I can add the constraint $y \le 10000 x$, but it is will exclude some parts of the solution space.

Answer (score 8):

You need a tolerance $\epsilon>0$, and you can strengthen your first two inequality constraints:
\begin{align}
\Gamma &= \theta x \\
\gamma &= \theta y \\
\epsilon y \le x &\le y
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but there is a problem. My model tends to maximize $\gamma$. So, it set $x=\epsilon$ to make $y=1$. However, based on logics, it should not do this.

Comment: Maybe your $\epsilon$ is not big enough to be considered "really" positive.

Answer (score 4):

There is no perfect fix for this, since strict inequalities are not supported in MILP models. So you will have to either live with the ambiguity when $x=0$ or exclude a portion of the solution space.